# Grep List of Words In File Containing HTML and Blank Spaces

Tags: html, linux, unix, grep

I am trying to grep a list of strings in file1 and file2.

file1 contains a list of strings

file2 contains a body of html text and some blank lines. Also the file does start with leading tab spaces.

I'm using the code:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2
```

However, I keep getting the full list of strings even though many are not present in file2.

Any idea why this is happening? I'm thinking something is wrong with the formatting of file2 that is throwing off grep.

Comment: Please provide a minimal viable example; in your case: simple sample files, too?!

Comment: Hey GhostCat, I just got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was able to find the answer online. It was not the formatting of the page.

I needed to do two things:

- Ignore case matching using the `grep -i` option
- Suppress the non-matching using the `grep -o` option

Hope this helps anyone working with strings and a body of text.